Display HTML front matter in a layout using Eleventy
I'm using Eleventy to generate pages for a blog. I have some HTML content in the front matter of my posts, but I cannot get it to display as HTML. When I reference it in my template, it's converted to HTML character entities.
This is what the post front matter looks like:
title: test
date: 2024-04-01
headerImage: american_flag_partial.jpg
imageCredit: Photo by <a
    href="https://unsplash.com/@timmossholder?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash">Tim
    Mossholder</a> on <a
    href="https://unsplash.com/photos/us-a-flag-on-white-and-red-striped-textile-QsX23A3NgMQ?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash">Unsplash</a>

In my post.njk template
{% if imageCredit %}{{ imageCredit }}{% endif %}
which renders
Photo by &lt;a href=&quot;https://unsplash.com/@timmossholder?utm_content=creditCopyText&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_source=unsplash&quot;&gt;Tim Mossholder&lt;/a&gt; on &lt;a href=&quot;https://unsplash.com/photos/us-a-flag-on-white-and-red-striped-textile-QsX23A3NgMQ?utm_content=creditCopyText&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_source=unsplash&quot;&gt;Unsplash&lt;/a&gt;

How can I prevent the string from being converted to HTML character entities? I've read through the 11ty documentation and I haven't discovered how to do this.

Okay, How to allow HTML to pass through a set block with Nunjucks helped me figure it out. It was nunjucks that was escaping the HTML.
changing
{% if imageCredit %}{{ imageCredit }}{% endif %}
to
{% if imageCredit %}{{ imageCredit | safe }}{% endif %}
in my post.njk template fixed the problem.
Some more info can be found in this SO question, Stop nunjucks from escaping HTML.
From the nunjucks manual
Safe
Mark the value as safe which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped. 

I thought safe would make it safe, not...unsafe....
